# Problems in versioning with .Net

Tags: .net, versioning

Our project has an assembly (let's call it IC), that is supposed to be used in many other projects (we call them Instruments). Our project use Instruments as well, and it uses reflection to get them, as they are installed separately (they work as plugins).

It is our requirement to sign IC assembly.

How do I handle versioning of IC in this case? We do not want to update/rebuild each instrument if we update IC, so we should support backward-compatibility. The instruments usually stay on the customer machine for long, even if we update out project or IC.

If we change version each IC modification - because IC is signed, it won't be accessible to the instruments that require old IC version. If we do not - we have a problem with "what was installed last, our project or Instrument?" If Instrument was installed the last one and it had an old IC with it, we are screwed.
Also we would like to ensure somehow that the project can be run as whole, is idea of iterating all project parts, checking the max IC version required and checking the version of IC itself via reflection is good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "IC" assembly needs to be treated as either an *immutable* or *versioned* assembly by your application, using the terminology from the [Assembly Versioning in Extensible Applications](http://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/vsbase/docs-master/html/edbfd3ce-43f4-4f3f-a90c-bc22bda19fae.htm) documentation. The primary difference between these is immutable assemblies **never**, while versioned assemblies use assembly binding redirection to support exclusively backwards-compatible changes.

The guidelines you'll need to follow include, but are not limited to:

1. Minimize the number of times you need to make changes to "IC" by making sure to include only the minimum set of interfaces required for it to provide the contracts used by the assemblies interacting with it.
2. Make sure to never introduce backwards-incompatible changes to the "IC" assembly. If you find you need to make a backwards-incompatible change (such as adding a method to an existing interface, or adding a parameter to an existing method), **stop and find a new way to do it**. For example, rather than add a method `MoreStuff` to `IMyInterface`, you can define a new interface `IMyInterface2` which includes the `MoreStuff` method. Just make sure your application can still handle objects which implement `IMyInterface` but do not also implement `IMyInterface2`.

Comment: Is binding redirection allows me to not to rebuild Instruments while changing the version of IC they use? (IC is signed). My first impression was that I still have to rebuild them

Comment: Archeg: That is correct, provided that the new version of IC is binary-backwards-compatible with the old version, this time using the terminology from this Breaking Changes Policy document. https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-uritemplate/blob/master/Docs.UriTemplate/Content/BreakingChangesPolicy.aml

Comment: Thanks! A lot of new info to try and think